# Error - COUNTIF with Text containing special characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I've tried using countif to count how many times text such as the ones shown below appear.

I've already searched a lot and I'm aware of the limitations that COUNTIF has for counting numeric data (such as the 15 characters limit).

But why isn't it working for the situation below, if it contains only Text?

```
LV3/SC*CZ2      1  (=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$2;A1)

LV3*CZ2         2  (=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$2;A2)
```

[image: Edit: Included Spreadsheet Image for Illustration]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd need to escape the "*". Use a tilde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the "*" which in `COUNTIF()`, as in some other functions, is known as a wildcard for zero or more characters. You'd need to escape such characters to make them match the symbol literally using a tilde. Try:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A$2,SUBSTITUTE(A1,"*","~*"))
```

I like [this](https://exceljet.net/glossary/wildcard) source for some more explaination on the topic.